# WPF windows forms host keyboard events

Tags: c#, wpf, winforms, winforms-interop

This is probably a simple question but i've been unable to find a quick answer.

I have a *WPF* application which has a *Windows Forms Control* hosting a GeckoFX component (doesn't really matter).

What i want to do is capture key down events inside the Windows Forms Control and grab focus of a WPF control for some particular key combination.
And what if i want to capture events from the entire WPF application window (even inside the Windows Forms Control)?
I tried handling the KeyDown event and PreviewKeyDown event but to no avail.

What i want to know is if this is possible and how this should be done. I can post some code if required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The KeyDown even on the Form should work for non special keys (like arrow keys). Use PreviewKeyDown to capture those, or use [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458748/wpf-onkeydown-not-being-called-for-space-key-in-control-derived-from-wpf-textb).

For GeckoWebBrowser specifically, I had to use PreviewKeyDown. Also, I added a line so it doesn't break in design mode:

```
private void webBrowser1_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, PreviewKeyDownEventArgs e) {
  if (DesignMode) return;
  if (!e.IsInputKey && e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.S) {
    DoStuff();
    return;
  }
}
```