# Keyboard keys Capturing

Tags: c#, wpf

I`m developing this application that need to read every key stroke while the application is focused.

I can read all keys except for 3 keys: Space bar, Enter and backspace.

This is a code snippet form my project:

XAML File:

```
<TextBox Height="108" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" KeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

CS File:

```
private void textBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Return || e.Key == Key.Space)
        MessageBox.Show("" + e.Key);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of KeyDown use PreviewKeyDown and your done -

```
<TextBox Height="108" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="12,12,0,0" Name="textBox1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="354" AcceptsReturn="True" AcceptsTab="True" PreviewKeyDown="textBox1_KeyDown" IsReadOnly="False" IsEnabled="True" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" />
```

Answer (score 0):

See this Link [WPF: OnKeyDown() not being called for space key in control derived from WPF TextBox.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458748/wpf-onkeydown-not-being-called-for-space-key-in-control-derived-from-wpf-textb)