# TextBox does not fire KeyDown event on spacebar

Tags: c#, wpf, keyboard

I have textbox catching KeyDown events like this:

```
 <Style TargetType="TextBox">
        <EventSetter Event="KeyDown" Handler="TextBoxInput"/>
    </Style>
```

It works for all key and key combinations except spacebar. Even space with modifiers works ok, only space alone does not come to my method.

Is there anything I can change on the textbox to fire the event also on spacebar alone?

Comment: possible duplicate of [WPF: OnKeyDown() not being called for space key in control derived from WPF TextBox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458748/wpf-onkeydown-not-being-called-for-space-key-in-control-derived-from-wpf-text)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `PreviewKeyDown` event instead of `KeyDown`.

```
<EventSetter Event="PreviewKeyDown" Handler="TextBoxInput"/>
```

And you can use [this article](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/wpf/thread/a96cf83c-9af7-4465-907b-7873104a8e1e) as backing for that.